# Clojure concurrency : Automating SQL Queries

Tags: sql, concurrency, clojure, functional-programming

I have a small program that is supposed to read SQL queries/commands one by one and execute them against a database.

If a query executes successfully, the next query is executed. 
If there is an error executing one query, the program should stop executing all together.

I have the code, except that the query still continues execution even when there is an exception.

```
(defn main
   []
   (loop [queries (get-all-queries)
          querycount 1]
     (let [q (first queries)]
        (println (format "currently processing query %s", querycount))
        (cond (nil? q) (println "All Queries ran successfully.")
              :else (do
                      (cond (= (:status (process-query q querycount)) "OK") 
                               (recur (rest queries) (+querycount 1)))
                      :else (println "An error occured while running queries")))))))


 (defn process-query
     [query query-count]
     (let [{query-body :query-body, is-query-running? :is-query-running?} query
           my-agent (agent 
                       {:error false, :query-count query-count} 
                       :error-handler handler-fn)]
        (send my-agent (fn[_]
                          (execute-query! db query-body)))))
        (loop [is-query-running? (is-query-running?)
               error? (:error @my-agent)]
           (cond error? (do (println "Error") 
                            {:status "ERROR" :error-msg (:error-msg @my-agent)})
           (and (not is-query-running?) (not error?)) (do (println "Success") 
                                                          {:status "OK"})
           (:else (do
                    (Thread/sleep 2000)
                    (recur (is-query-running?) (:error @my-agent)))))))


(defn handler-fn
  [agent exception]
  (println (format "an exception occured : %s" exception))
  (if (instance? java.sql.BatchUpdateException exception)
      (println (.getNextException exception)))
  (send agent (? [_] {:error true, :error-message exception}))
  (throw exception))
```

The reason why I'm using an agent is that I have some queries that take 4 hours to run.
and when that happens, the database does not notify the program that the query has been completed. instead, the program is stuck. so, instead, I constantly poll to check if the query is done already.

- Is this the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to do ?
- Should I be using any other concurrency primitives ?
- Do I  even need concurrency primitives ?
- I've been thinking about this for a long time now.

Comment: How does `is-query-running?` work. That's not clear from your code, since it gets passed in as a value in each query map, and may be essential to the problem, because `process-query` will return `"OK"` if `is-query-running?` becomes false before the agent's `:error` key becomes true.

Comment: is-query-running? runs a query and retrieves all the actively executing queries, then checks if the current query is among those running. if so, it returns true.

Comment: If it returns `true` and not itself, you should get an error message in the `recur` call in `process-query`. Clojure is a Lisp-1, so the return value `true` would shadow the function definition of `is-query-running?` inside the `loop`.

Comment: Dude, please format your source code in 80 columns max.

Comment: @Igrapenthin, sorry Dude. Code formatted.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to use core.async to resolve this kind of workflow
Take a look at http://clojure.com/blog/2013/06/28/clojure-core-async-channels.html
This lib will let you to check your conditions with the related asynchronous tasks involved

A few resources that may help you
http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/07/core-async
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AhxcGGeh5ho

Answer (score 1):

The main problem seems to be: on the one hand, you write that the long queries never return, i.e. they don't even throw exceptions. On the other hand, your error detection mechanism for the agent is based on catching an exception.

I think what you need to do is not check (primarily) whether an exception was caught, but whether `execute-query` has actually returned a valid result when `is-query-running?` returns false.

Regarding the right concurrency primitive, I would suggest using a future instead of an agent. They are simpler than agents, since they can only return a single value, instead of changing their state multiple times, and their way of error handling is to simply return the exception instead of the regular return value.

You can then follow this implementation idea: in the loop, do a `deref` with timeout on the future. If the return value of the `deref` is whatever `execute-query!` returns regularly, return `"OK"`(resp. add a second expression to the `future` body as a clearly identifiable return value, e.g. the keyword `:ok`). Otherwise, if the return value of the `deref` is an exception, return `"ERROR"` with the `:error-msg` from the exception like you do now. Finally, if the return value is the timeout value you gave to the `deref`, call `is-query-running?`. If it's true, loop another time, if it's false, return `ERROR` with a special `:error-msg` which communicates that your query ended without either returning nor throwing an exception. (And probably call `future-cancel` so you don't leak threads of never-ending `execute-query!` calls.)